# Namespace and class same but diff package name how we use?

Tags: c#, .net-core

the Problem is we have two package they same namespace and same class .method but diff only in package name now i have to import both of them into single file but use individual method from diff class.

while, migrate from .NET Framework to .NET Core i noticed that some method is coming from multiple package due to which they conflict to each other.

In my case `SipException` class is coming from `Microsoft.Skype.SipStack` as well as `SIPEPS` package.

One of which looks like:

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.Skype.SipStack, Version=1.0.20132.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// C:\Users\t-gamund\.nuget\packages\microsoft.skype.sipstack\1.0.20132.3\lib\net462\Microsoft.Skype.SipStack.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Sip
{
    public class SipException : Exception
    {
        public SipException();
        public SipException(string message);
        public SipException(string message, Exception innerException);
        protected SipException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
    }
}
```

it look like similar to two package having same namespace and similar class now we have to use particular class using particular package. but i do not know how i do.
if can guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#example-1) to create aliases:

```
using MSSipException = Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Sip.SipException;
```